# Returning CGo String from Go function to Python program

Tags: python, c, go

So i'm trying to return a string result from a go function to a python string. So far I am returning a `*C.char` from go and getting this into python, I am just having trouble de-referencing of the pointer, since this is something I am not familiar with in python.

Go part:

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

//export HelloGo
func HelloGo(a string) *C.char {
    fmt.Println("Go recieved:", a)
    return C.CString(fmt.Sprintf("Hello from Go, %s!", a))
}

func main() {}
```

Python part:

```
import ctypes as c

text = b"PYTHON MESSAGE"

lib = c.cdll.LoadLibrary("./hey.so")

class GoString(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("p", c.c_char_p), ("n", c.c_longlong)]

lib.HelloGo.argtypes = [GoString]
gs = GoString(text, len(text))
result = c.c_char_p(lib.HelloGo(gs))

print("Python reads:", result)
```

output:

```
Go recieved: PYTHON MESSAGE
Python reads: c_char_p(4607968)
```

I have tried using `result.value` and `c_string_from(result)`, but these give me a segmentation fault. I have had no difficulty getting the result in a C program and understand I can write a Python extension to retrieve this but this seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://savorywatt.com/2015/09/18/calling-go-code-from-python-code/ it explains how you can export go functions so they can be used in other languages

Comment: cheers, I had been following this: https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf which also has some useful examples. I've got it to work with Ints and even single characters just full strings have been a problem. I think i'm following the go pointer passing rules but not sure. https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers assuming that a *C.char is a c pointer not a go one.

Comment: The saverywatt site says nothing about returning strings to python however.